# django south migrations sqlite to postgres on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I've been working stupidly without database migrations since django 1.2 and I've said enough is enough, time to get up with the times seeing as 1.7 brings in db migrations.  So south is all new to me, It's been a rough ride trying to get things working straight, and right now I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it working on heroku.

I think I might have made things a lot worse by leaving it this late to add south to my project.  My initial problems have been getting the transition from local to heroku and being able to then migrate the data.  Right now I'm getting `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "campaign_id" of relation "beaconmanager_beacon" already exists` when trying to run migrate on `beaconmanager`.

I guess what I need to know right now is:

1. Does south work with different databases, as I have sqlite3 for local development but my dev heroku server runs with Postgres?
2. The error above, would it be better to delete my migrations folders and then attempt to run `convert_to_south` on all of my apps?
3. What is the correct way of actually using south on heroku – I've noticed that migrations should be made on local and then pushed to heroku, but do we run `schemamigration myapp --auto` or just `migrate myapp`.

Sorry if this sounds like beginner stuff, but I have literally just picked up south.

Answer (score 0):

**Working on heroku and south migrations you have to fallow this steps.**

1) Generate schemamigrations files in develop environment. (/.manage.py schemamigration [app_name] --auto).

2) Add these files to the git repository.

3) Push the git repository to heroku.

4) Apply the migrations on heroku environment (heroku run /.manage.py migrate [app_name])

**If you want to reset south migrations:**

1) Delete the schemamigration files.

2) Flush south  migration_history table, if you want to delete only one app in migration_history you can use firfox addon SqlLite manager for   delete only app records in develop environment. (in production environment use database manager provider).

3) Convert your app to south (./manage.py convert_to_south [app_name])

4) Make model changes

5) Create shemamigration files

6) Migrate app

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however I've moved over to 1.7 now, so no longer have a requirement for south.  Thanks you for taking the time to answer this though.